# Why does the option fontupper not work in tcblisting of tcolorbox?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

Please see the following MWE for my queries. Thank you.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry,tcolorbox}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
Question 1:\\
Why does \verb|fontupper=\huge| not work?\\
How to enlarge the fontsize?

\begin{tcblisting}{fontupper=\huge,listing side text,righthand ratio=0.4,sidebyside gap=4mm,}
\rule{1in}{5pt} some text some text some text some text some text
\end{tcblisting}

Question 2:\\
Why is there an indent on the second line of leftside of the box?\\
And how to eliminate this indent?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really that `fontupper=\huge` doesn't have any effect. If you were to put `fontupper=\huge Hello`, then "Hello" would be huge. What's happening is that the style options for the listing are taking over and resetting everything once the listing starts.

You should read the [documentation for the `listings` package](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf); that's what matters here, together with the `listing style` and `listing options` for the `tcblisting` environment which set those options.

By default, with the tcblistings library, you're getting `listing style=tcblatex`. Apparently that style puts in `breaklines=true` and a non-zero value for `breakindent`, which is why you're seeing the indent on the second line.

You could define your own listing style, and use that. Or you could just set the options for the listings package with `listing options=`. E.g., to make it huge and have no indent:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
Question 1:\\
Why does \verb|fontupper=\huge| not work?\\
How to enlarge the fontsize?

\begin{tcblisting}{listing side text,
listing options={breakindent=0pt,breaklines=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily\huge},
righthand ratio=0.4,sidebyside gap=4mm}
\rule{1in}{5pt} some text some text some text some text some text
\end{tcblisting}

Question 2:\\
Why is there an indent on the second line of leftside of the box?\\
And how to eliminate this indent?
\end{document}
```

Not exactly pretty, but you get the idea.

[image: tcblisting output]